# Bash - How to Write Output to Multiple Variables in Parallel?

Tags: bash, performance

I have a command that takes  about 100ms to run, and have to run it multiple times without any delays for a script while storing its output

Non-parallel code snippet:

```
DISCSUBTITLE=$(quodlibet --print-playing "<discsubtitle>")
TITLE=$(quodlibet --print-playing "<title>")
ARTIST=$(quodlibet --print-playing "<artist>")
ALBUM=$(quodlibet --print-playing "<album>")
STATE=$(quodlibet --status)

echo "$DISCSUBTITLE - $TITLE / $ARTIST / $ALBUM"
echo $STATE #actual program does regex processing on $STATE
```

This took about 0.55 seconds on my machine due to repeated calls to `quodlibet`. For my intended purpose, that's too slow and causes noticeable stutters.

After some research & some helpful answers, I've gotten 3 decent solutions explored in order of speed.

1. **Using `&`, writing to temporary files.**

```
#This allows easy changing of file directory and/or name
prefix="/tmp/quodlibet_status_"

quodlibet --print-playing "<discsubtitle>" > $prefix'DISCSUBTITLE' &
quodlibet --print-playing "<title>" > $prefix'TITLE' &
quodlibet --print-playing "<artist>" > $prefix'ARTIST' &
quodlibet --print-playing "<album>" > $prefix'ALBUM' &
quodlibet --status > $prefix'STATE' &

wait

DISCSUBTITLE=$(< $prefix'DISCSUBTITLE')
TITLE=$(< $prefix'TITLE')
ARTIST=$(< $prefix'ARTIST')
ALBUM=$(< $prefix'ALBUM')
STATE=$(< $prefix'STATE')

echo "$DISCSUBTITLE - $TITLE / $ARTIST / $ALBUM"
echo $STATE
```

This is my chosen solution as it's the most straightforward and also fastest. It took about 0.16 seconds on my SSD, and 0.18 on my HDD. Over 3x speedup.
I initially didn't think of using temp files because I wrongly assumed writing to the disk would be messy and take too much time. This is massively faster compared to other 'every day' disk operations that are on the scale of many megabytes and usually involve other operations alongside.

2. **Program specific. Minimizing calls.**

```
LONG=$(quodlibet --print-playing /
    "<discsubtitle|<discsubtitle> - ><title> / <artist> / <album>")
#Upon research & fiddling, I've found that the --print-playing command
#for my program uses substitution when outputting the string similar to
#markup languages, so you can basically print any information
#however you want.

STATE=$(quodlibet --status)
#STATE has to be separate

echo $LONG
echo $STATE
```

This took about 0.21 seconds on my machine, and is my fallback solution.
Somewhat restrictive and depends heavily on program used.

3. **GNU Parallel/Parset**

```
. $(which env_parallel.bash)
parset "DISCSUBTITLE TITLE ARTIST ALBUM STATE" ::: \
    "quodlibet --print-playing '<discsubtitle>'" \
    "quodlibet --print-playing '<title>'" \
    "quodlibet --print-playing '<artist>'" \
    "quodlibet --print-playing '<album>'" \
    "quodlibet --status"

echo "$DISCSUBTITLE - $TITLE / $ARTIST / $ALBUM"
echo $STATE
```

This took about 0.35 seconds on my machine. Not really ideal for me, but technically still a decent margin faster.
One of the comments mentioned it being effectively an automated version of solution 1.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The which code have you tried and why you think it is not working? There is nothing parallel in the code you posted.

Comment: @RaisonD'etre: In addition to what Poshi said, your example code does not store any output of a command in a variable. Aside from this, if one execution of a command takes only a tenth of a second, I don't think you gain a lot by parallelizing everything, because you loose additional time for setting up the parallel processes. What you could do is to "bundle" the commands. For instance, if you have 10000 commands to execute, you could  create 100 files, each running 100 commands sequentially, and run those "master files" in parallel.

Comment: You are looking for `parset`: `parset var1,var2,var3,var4 cmd --print ::: a b c d`. `parset` is part of newer versions of GNU Parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using temporary files

```
cmd1 > out1 &
cmd2 > out2 &
cmd3 > out3 &
cmd4 > out4 &

wait

var1=$(< out1)
var2=$(< out2)
var3=$(< out3)
var4=$(< out4)

echo "$var1 $var2 $var3 $var4"
```

Comment: This is basically what `parset` does, but it adds GNU Parallel syntax, and cleans up the temporary files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with `read` so you only run `cmd` once:

```
read a b c < <(cmd --printA --printB --printC)
```

You may have to fiddle with IFS depending how `cmd` works.